# String to exponential notation

Tags: ruby, exponential

I use Ruby. 
I have `str="0.2592585e7"`
I need to convert this to exp notation and get the same result like `x=0.2592585e7` 
When I do this via format I get: 
`irb(main):064:0> format("%0.6e", str.to_f)
=> "2.592585e+06"`
Any idea how to not get decimal before point ?

Comment: "I need to convert this to exp notation and get the same result like x=0.2592585e7" - huh? It's already a valid number string in scientific notation. Just do `str.to_f` to get the number.

Comment: In your case I get - irb(main):002:0> result =  str.to_f
=> 2592585.0
But I need 0.2592585e7

Comment: It's the same number. For all practical purposes, there is no difference. Mind explaining _why_ you think you need that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can convert a string to float like this:

```
str = "0.2592585e7"

puts result = str.to_f / 10000000
```

or

```
str = "0.2592585e7"
result =  str.to_f

puts result.to_i
```

To get an integer

Comment: They're not trying to get an integer, though. Also not sure what that ` / 10000000` is supposed to be doing.